# Char array replace characters

Tags: java, json, escaping

I'm creating json response in quite sophisticated framework and have problems with json escaping.

I'm able to grab `char[]` with text I'd like to escape. What's the proper (and the best in case of performance) way to do escaping. Keep in mind that it's not replacing character with character - it's replacing (mostly) one character with two characters, so the array has to be rearranged.

Using common (Apache, Google, ...) libraries would be appreciated.

---

edit:

Gson library looks fine for my purposes, however there's a problem with snippet:

```
Gson gson2 = new Gson();
String json = gson2.toJson(new String(buf));
```

cause it encodes html as well. My task is to do just json encoding for given HTML markup, so I don't want to have tags encoded like `\u003e`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I alway use Gson from Google. It work fine for me and no escaping problems I meat ever. Try it.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

// To json:
String result = gson.toJson(yourObject);

// From json:
YourObject object= gson.fromJson(result, YourObject.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.disableHtmlEscaping();
String result = builder.create().toJson(yourObject);
```